useCookie in Nuxt 3
I use Nuxt 3, Vue 3 and pinia. I try to set cookies:
stores/auth.ts


import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: 'auth',
  state: () => {
    return {
      token: useCookie('token')
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async userToken({ userId }) {
      const { data, pending }: any = await useFetch('/api/auth', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: {
          userId
        },
      });

        const token = useCookie('token', {
          maxAge: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
          sameSite: 'strict',
          secure: true,
        })

        token.value = data?.value?.token;  
    }
  }
})



page/Login.vue


<script>
  import { mapState, storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
  import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth';
</script>

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'LogIn',
  data() {
    return {
      userId: 1
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useAuthStore, ['token']),
  },
  
  methods: {
    async getUserToken() {
      const { userToken } = useAuthStore();
      await userToken({ userId: this.userId });

      const { token } = storeToRefs(useAuthStore()); // exist on Localhost, does not exist on site.domail.com
      console.log(token)
    }
  },
})
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ token }}</div> <!-- exist on Localhost, does not exist on site.domail.com -->
    <button @click="getUserToken"> log in </button>
  </div>
</template>



When I work on Localhost it works, this and other cookies are saved. But after biulding (npm run server-build) and deploy to Staging - it does not work. There are not cookies at all. What is wrong and what should i do?
Thank you

Does it work if you build locally? What is server-build? Any errors in the browser console?

It works locally, no errors in the browser console

No errors on staging? Can you try to set a button to create an old-school cookie with vanilla JS? Can you try to deploy it elsewhere like Netlify for troubleshooting purposes?

It starts to work when i delete "secure: true". I do not know if it is bad practice..

Give a read to that one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#block_access_to_your_cookies
